# find and replace 4 characters or columns from end of line

Tags: windows, notepad++, regex

I have a large database with text and 4 digit numbers:

```
wide receipt 5245  
seacrest john mason field - rogue 5524  
charly rose/flower - return deemed creed 7532
```

I want to sort them so that the numbers can be used to classify each line (as a column) - preferably with search and replace for comma ", " so that I can use the separator to force the column

Desired output:

```
wide receipt, 5245  
seacrest john mason field - rogue, 5524  
charly rose/flower - return deemed creed, 7532
```

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I replace ' nnnn' with ', nnnn'?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)

**Solution 1** (preserves trailing spaces):

This solution preserves the trailing spaces in the test data.

- Set "Find what" to `(.*?) ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1, \2`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Solution 2** (removes trailing spaces):

Uses different "Find what" and "Replace with" values (from comment by [SalvoF](https://superuser.com/users/458082/salvof)).

This solution removes the trailing spaces from the test data.

- Set "Find what" to `\s(\d{4})\s*$`
- Set "Replace with" to `, \1`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpGL6.png)

**Before**:

```
wide receipt 5245  
seacrest john mason field - rogue 5524  
charly rose/flower - return deemed creed 7532
```

**After**:

```
wide receipt, 5245
seacrest john mason field - rogue, 5524
charly rose/flower - return deemed creed, 7532
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Nice solution. I don't use this software, but after reading its wiki page on regexes, I would search for `\s(\d{4})$` and replace it with `, \1`.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't work with my test file. The test data in the question has trailing spaces.

Comment: My guess: you copied lines to work on from this page, they've got a final space on them, except for the last one.

Comment: Well, assuming spaces are on the original file, search for `\s(\d{4})\s*$` then.

Comment: I just checked again. You're correct, and that why it initially replaced only the last  one. I then edited the question to copy the test data and all the lines have trailing spaces, so there are no matches with your regexp.

Comment: Yes, that works. Updating answer to provide alternate solution. Thanks.

Comment: @SalvoF Nice solution. Why not post it as a separate answer?

Comment: Thank you @Excellll. I think David did a good job by posting the idea in a clear way.